# Inflate layout inside Constraint Layout bottomToTop of another view syntax

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to inflate a view inside a constraint layout, but I cant figure out the correct syntax for the view to be on top of another view:

[image]

```
    VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.topToTop = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    params.leftToLeft = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;
    params.rightToRight = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID;


    params.bottomToTop = // unsure what the correct syntax for this is;

    mParentLayout.addView(videoView, params);
```

I want to make it above the green guideline `mGuideline`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/challengeroom_gl_hori_50"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

Parent Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/challengeroom_cl_parent_layout">
```

Comment: You would assign `mGuideline`'s ID to that field. If you've defined that `Guideline` in the layout XML, it would be `R.id.whatever_id_you_set_there`. If you created the `Guideline` dynamically in code, you would need to assign it one with `setId(int)`, and then use that for `bottomToTop`'s value.

Comment: I set Guideline in XML and changed it to ```params.bottomToTop= R.id.challengeroom_gl_hori_50;``` however it's making the constraint stretch all the way to the bottom of the parent layout. https://i.imgur.com/n98WMdj.png

Comment: I just got a chance to test this, and it works as expected for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ6zq.png. Are you sure that `mParentLayout` is your `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: Yeah I checked many times :/ ```@BindView(R.id.challengeroom_cl_parent_layout)
    ConstraintLayout mParentLayout;``` I'll try it again in a new project.

Comment: Oh, no, wait. I didn't actually test the posted snippet. I tested the corrected version inadvertently. I'm doing it in a Kotlin project, so I didn't copy/paste, and just subconsciously entered the correct `LayoutParams`. Duh. You don't want `MATCH_PARENT` for the constructor arguments. You want `0` for both.

Comment: That fixed it!!!! Thanks a bunch, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I didn't catch that yesterday. Glad you got it working. Cheers!